# git set upstream branch to branch i want to merge into

Tags: git

I mistakenly set my upstream branch to the branch I wanted to merge into and then pushed my commits to the remote branch. However, I now realize that this was a mistake, and I want to undo the changes to get the remote branch back to its previous state. The affected branch is being used by multiple developers, so it's crucial to undo the changes without causing any further issues. Can someone please suggest a safe and efficient way to undo the upstream branch changes and restore the remote branch to its previous state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To undo changes on `target_branch` on the remote :

- search for the sha of the commit it should be at (you can find it either in your local history, or in the activity log of your remote repository),
- run: `git push --foce-with-lease origin <sha>:target_branch`

As a generic advice: do inform your colleagues that you accidentally made a force push to revert your first action, in case one of them based his/her work on the intermediate state.

---

To update the remote tracking branch of your current branch :

```
git branch -u origin/my_branch
# instead of
# git branch -u origin/target_branch
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought i was going to have to pull an all nighter. <3